# change in header file -- when to recompile in c

Tags: c, header-files, recompile

In C, I have a header file `file1_0.h` which is included by only `file1.h` and `file1.c`.

`file1.h` is included by many other files say, `file2.c`, `file3.c` and `file4.c`

If I make any change in `file1_0.h` I know that I need to re-compile `file1.c` but do I also need to recompile `file2.c`, `file3.c` and `file4.c` ?

Comment: Create a makefile with dependency rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

All your other files depend on `file1_0.h` since `file1.h` depends on it and all the others depend on `file1.h`. So you need to recompile "to be safe".